# Require JS globals in immediately-invoked function expression

Tags: angularjs, jshint, iife

We are using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) to lint our Javascript. All of our AngularJS files are wrapped in an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
(function() {
  // some AngularJS code
})();
```

Is there any configuration for ESLint to assert that all globals (e.g. `angular`) are arguments of the immediately-invoked function. **I do not want to add angular as a global in JSHint**, as this will allow all `angular` references. I only want to allow it as a global, if it is part of the immediately-invoked function.

**Invalid:**

```
(function() {
  angular.module(...)
})();
```

**Valid:**

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module(...)
})(angular);
```

Any Ideas?